# What's the main reason to prefer List(interface) over Linkedist etc(implementations)

Tags: java, linked-list

Suppose we wanna define and use a LinkedList in our code.
I would define it this way:

```
LinkedList<String> list= new LinkedList<>();
```

Why some people use the interface List

```
List<String> list = new LinkedList<>();
```

to define a LinkedList? What are the advantages?

Answer (score 0):

If you use following :

```
List<String> list = new LinkedList<>();
```

Then everywhere, in your code, you just using `List<String> list`. It means, that if you want use `ArrayList`, the only thing you have to do is to change one line : `List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();` and it will work perfectly in all other code, no matter how complex it is.

If you are using LinkedList, you can have huge problems with switching to something else.